# How to end the supplementary part?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I am writing a thesis and after some chapters I would like to include some supplementary information. I use

```
\beginsupplement
```

to start my supplement . But how do I end it? My next chapter does now also contain figures and tables that start with 'S'.

I also used:

```
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use an environment. Environments use grouping, so changes that you make at the start don't affect things after the environment ends. As a demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{fred}{\renewcommand\aaa{AAA}}{}
\newcommand\aaa{BBB}
\begin{document}
\aaa
\begin{fred}
\aaa
\end{fred}
\aaa
\end{document}
```

This produces BBB AAA BBB. Your case is similar; just put the `\renewcommand`s and `\setcounter`s in the first argument to `\newenvironment`.

Comment: This really sounds like the solution... except that is does not work (yet). Did I do something wrong? I now used:
`\newenvironment{SI}
{\setcounter{table}{0}
      \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\thechapter\arabic{table}}%
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\thechapter\arabic{figure}}%
     \setcounter{equation}{0}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{S\thechapter\arabic{equation}}%
  }` and then in text `\begin{SI}` and `\end{SI}`

Comment: I could fix it with also defining a new command for the beginning of new chapter

Comment: @BrigitteBruijns, too: Note, however, that the assignment made by `\setcounter` is always `\global`, that is, it is *not* confined to the environment (or, more generally, to the group) where it is executed.

Comment: @BrigitteBruijns can you share the code for the change you did to the chapter? I tried and couldn't make it work

Comment: I need to look it up, it is now a year ago I defended my thesis ;)

Comment: In the first chapter (with a supplement): \beginsupplement
In the next chapter: \AddLabels and \SetBgContents{}

Comment: Thanks, I ended up coming up with my own solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524399/170518

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. Posting as it may be useful for others.

In the preamble

```
% make supplementary sections in chapters be numbered with letters
\newcommand{\opensupplement}{
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}
}
% restore the numbering system to arabic for the following chapter's sections
\newcommand{\closesupplement}{
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
}
```

In the document:

```
\opensupplement

\section{Supplementary section 1}
(...)
\section{Supplementary section 2}
(...)
\closesupplement
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, where after using `\beginsupplment` every other chapter started with S1-SX. My solution was to create a new command to close the supplements and restore the table and figure labels to `chapter.figure`

```
 \newcommand{\closesupplement}{
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
     \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
     }
```